# Steps to Update a Wordpress Plugin That We Developed

Tags: plugin-development

We have our own Wordpress plugin for our site.  Someone developed it for us some time ago.  I am generally aware of how it works and am able to code PHP, JS, etc. and have made some mods on the plugin over the years.

I am wanting to know what the steps are to updating the plugin and making sure it is ready for the newest version of Wordpress as it hasn't been updated in about 2 years.

Is there a flowchart of steps needed to walk through to make sure a plugin is as it should be?

Comment: The best solution would be to install the latest version of WordPress on a *Test Server* and then install your specific plugin after that. [Enable Debugging ( Display & Log )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and iron out any issues that arise. Finally, install any other plugins you plan to have on your live website to ensure it play nicely with those plugins. There's not really a "Flowchart" for this kind of thing that I know of as in 2 years so much has changed .

Comment: So if I do the test and no issues arise I assume all is well?  This is a plugin that others will download, so do plugin developers have a set of standard plugins they also install to make sure there won't be compatibility issues?

Comment: I see, if you plan on allowing others to download this plugin I suggest reading [Writing a Plugin - WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), [Best Practices - WP Handbook](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/), [Plugin Development - WP Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/). There's probably a TON more resources on google you could also find but these are straight from the horse's mouth ( so to speak ) to ensure your plugin is accepted into the WP Repository.